# Constructors and Exceptions

Tags: c++

I was reading some notes on C++ and came across the following question

> Q: Can a constructor throws an exception? How to handle the error when the constructor fails?
>
> A:The constructor never throws an error.

Now this answer kind of confused me and just to make sure I went [online](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors-can-throw.html) and read that you could always throw exceptions from a constructor. I just wanted to make sure if this way a typo in the notes and that I may not be missing something important.

Comment: Given that `new` can throw, I'd say that your "A" is wrong.

Comment: Maybe it means "the constructor cannot return an error, so the idiomatic way of notifying a construction error is to throw an exception"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notes are wrong, if they're talking about constructors in general. Ctors can indeed throw normally. Perhaps that was discussing a particular class which guarantees nonthrow construction?

On the other hand, it's strongly encouraged to code so that your **destructors** never throw. It's legal for them to do so, but throwing an exception during stack unwinding results in immediate program termination (a call to `std::terminate`).

Answer (score 4):

Of course, it can. Even standard containers (e.g. `std::vector`) throw `std::bad_alloc` from constructors. This [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors-can-throw.html) is telling the truth.

Comment: You linked to the same FAQ as the OP did. :)

Comment: @DavidO LOL, I obviously need to rephrase the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can throw an exception from a constructor, but be careful: if object is not properly constructed, destructor will not be called.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int i)
    {
        throw i;
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "~Foo()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Foo f(42);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Catched" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Catched
```

To fix this you should encapsulate one constructor into another:

```
Foo()
{

}

Foo(int i): Foo()
{
    throw i;
}
```

Output:

```
~Foo()
Catched
```

Comment: Although the destructor is not executed, no memory is leaked in your first example. (Observed with valgrind)

Comment: Never have catch-all clause without (re)throw or you gonna have a bad time.

Comment: @stefan, even if valgrind doesn't show memory leak, in first case memory will be leaked.